# WKWebView - how to set encoding to string content

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView, which I provide data form CoreData, loading it in string

Code is following

```
  var webView:WKWebView?

  override func viewDidLoad() {

  webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 250, view.bounds.width - 20, 1500))
  self.view.addSubview(webView!)
  var contentString = body // variable with preloaded data
  webView!.loadHTMLString(contentString!, baseURL: nil)

  }
```

webView loads with broken encoding, like this

[image]

How to fix that ?

Comment: html content from CoreData

Comment: Most probably, `var contentString = body` already contains a wrong string, and you should solve that first.